Prove: $(n+1)^n = \binom{n+1}{1}n^n - \binom{n+1}{2}(n-1)^n + \binom{n+1}{3}(n-2)^n + \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{n}1^n$
I was working on sums of cubes and sums of fourth powers and I ended up with the above.
As examples, for $n = 3$, we have $ 4^4 = \binom{4}{1}3^3 - \binom{4}{2}2^3 + \binom{4}{3}1^3 = 108 - 48 + 4 = 64$
for $n = 5$, we have $$\begin{align}  6^5 &= \binom{6}{1}5^5 - \binom{6}{2}4^5 + \binom{6}{3}3^5 - \binom{6}{4}2^5 + \binom{6}{5}1^5 \\&= 18750 - 15360 + 4860 - 480 + 6 = 7776 \end{align} $$
Not sure how one would prove this!

Looks like an inclusion-exclusion result.

What have you tried? My first line of attack would be to blitz both sides with the binomial theorem (once on the left and $n$ times on the right) and see what came up.

Specifically, $(n+1)^n$ counts the number of functions ${1,\dots,n}\mapsto{1,\dots,n+1}$ that are not onto, which is all of them, and the right side is the inclusion-exclusion count of the same thing.

Verified. Also induction doesn't work.

More generally, the number of functions from a set of $n$ elements to a set of $m$ element sets that are not onto is $$\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{i-1}\binom{m}i(m-i)^n.$$ So this will be true for any $m>n.$

So, when $m>n,$ $$m^n=\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{i-1}\binom mi (m-i)^n.$$

Brilliant observation!

This question is similar to: How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^ki^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom {k+1}{i} =(k+1)^k$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. ...

(cont.) Note that, in addition to using $k$ instead of $n$, this other question's equation is just in a somewhat different form, e.g., using $(-1)^j=(-1)^{j-2}$ and $\binom{n+1}{j}=\binom{n+1}{n+1-j}$.

One could also derive this formula via the Laplace interpolation formula for $f(x)=x^n$ and the nodes $x_k=k$, $k=0,1,...,n+1$.

Consider the set $A$ of all functions $\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,m\}.$ Let $A_i$ be the subset of all functions that do not have $i$ in the image.
Then $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_m$ is all such functions which are not onto, and inclusion-exclusion gives us:
$$\left|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_m\right|=\sum_{i=1}^m (-1)^{i-1}\binom mi (m-i)^n$$
Of course, if $m>n,$ all such functions are not onto, so you get: $$m^n=|A|=|A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_m|= \sum_{i=1}^m (-1)^{i-1}\binom mi (m-i)^n$$ Your case is the case when $m=n+1.$
If $m=n,$ you get that the sum on the right is $m^m-m!.$

The sums got from $k=0$ to $m$ because, in most cases, it adds zero to include $m$, but when $m=n=0,$ you do get $1$ since $0^0=1$ combinatorially.
